# typeerror: cannot read property of undefined javascript - empty JSON object from fetch despite postman showing object from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app is supposed to attain a JSON object to display information onto dashboard. There is an object when I check postman using the URL which is what I want to use however when trying to access the fields from the object I am getting a type error of undefined javascript. Even when I console log the object it is an empty array.

The below is the fetch request which has worked for all other aspects of the application but not for this part of it.

API call in Postman using the same URL gives the following response:

```
[
    {
        "average_hb": "85.27",
        "average_os": "92.84",
        "max_hb": "86.35",
        "max_os": "96.54"
    }
]
```

`get/` call response on chrome developer tools:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/utilisation/T/detail/get/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 79
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 07 Sep 2021 21:07:37 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.7
Vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

The outcome I would like from this is to be able to display the values of the four variables (`average_hb` etc.) onto application. These fields come from Django back end which as mentioned, does return an object when looking in postman.

```
function UtilisationDetail(props){   

    var average_hb = 0;
    var average_os = 0;
    var max_hb = 0;
    var max_os = 0;

    const [utilisations, setUtilisation] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/utilisation/${props.warehouseState}/detail/get/`, {
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then( resp => resp.json())
            .then(resp => setUtilisation(resp))
            // .catch( error => console.log(error) )     
    }, [props.warehouseState]) 

    function setDetails(){
        try{
            console.log(utilisations)
            average_hb = utilisations[0].average_hb;
            average_os = utilisations[0].average_os;
            max_hb = utilisations[0].max_hb;
            max_os = utilisations[0].max_os;
        }
        catch(e){

        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {setDetails}
            <h4>Space</h4>

                <p>Average HB {average_hb}</p>
                <p>Average OS {average_os}</p>
                <p>Max HB {max_hb}</p>
                <p>Max OS {max_os}</p>
          
        </div>
    )




}

export default UtilisationDetail;
```

Comment: Well, you never call `setDetails`, you just render it, which makes no sense since it doesn't return anything -- but you're not rendering the return value but the variable which points to the function, so again not calling it. But inside of `setDetails` you reference `[0]`, so maybe the response is not an array? I can't help further without seeing the response from the server.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I have tried different methods of calling setDetails (even after the fetch call to implicitly call it) but this has not done anything different. What info do you need from server response and i will try get it? It is giving me a 200 code for the get call which is fine but I dont seem to be getting an object back. It wouldnt be an array that is returned as it is only a single object so i have got the terminology wrong there but I just want a way of accessing the single object.

Comment: Well if the API response isn't returning data then that's your problem. Not the front-end code. If you are getting an object (you imply that the same request in Postman show data) then I would need to see that response.

Comment: Ok thanks I have added that above if that is what you mean - i have tried to get screenshot but its not letting me add them yet.

Comment: @lekocast What's the actual responds you get in the browser. The headers look good.

Comment: thanks for looking into it Brandon/Dominik. Answer from TR3 seems to have worked a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another useEffect for `setDetails()` that is dependent on `utilisations`, and have a guard against the `utilisations.length`

```
useEffect(() => {

if(utilisations.length) setDetails()

}, [utilisations])
```

And then handle your `return` statement differently to render the output.